# Do you have a community event planned for 2016?

Tags: discussion

The SDL Web (Tridion) community continues to grow and evolve. In addition to online activities, webinars, and user groups, within the last few years we've also seen conferences and SDL-sponsored developer days and a hackathon.

**Do you have a community-related event planned for 2016?**

If so, please share:

- Your event name
- A link to the event details or sponsoring group
- Planned or tentative date(s)

*Optionally include details such as intended audience, previous event successes, contact information, etc.*

Happy New Year and thanks for making 2015 awesome.

Answer (score 8):

Event Name: 3rd **Tridion Developer Summit** - 2016

**Event Date: 11 - 12, May 2016**

[www.tridiondevelopersummit.com](http://www.tridiondevelopersummit.com)

Early-bird registrations until 15 March

Event Location: Amsterdam, Netherlands

Event Purpose: Learning & Knowledge Sharing, Professional Networking

Comment: Can't wait for this one. So much to announce! So much has changed since September, it's amazing.

Comment: Is there any live feed or recording for sessions ?

Answer (score 6):

**Event Name:** 2nd SDL Web Developer Summit India - 2016

**Event Link:** [SDL Web Dev Summit India](https://community.sdl.com/developers/sdl-developer-summit-india-2016/c/e/179)

**Event Date:** 5th and 6th Feb 2016

**Event Location:** New Delhi, India

**Event Purpose:** Learning & Knowledge Sharing, Professional Networking

Comment: Can't wait for this, it's going to be awesome.

Comment: The feeling is mutual Nuno.
Trying our best to make it as big as possible - awesomeness is assured :)